# Gdb doesn't "see" breakpoint i have put, so it runs through whole program

Tags: c, gdb

I am following tutorial from yt, by Liveoverflow.
So point is that i should disassemble a program, but I couldn't successfully stop it at breaking point i made so it run the whole code.
I have done exact same steps as shown in the video but i got different results...

I have searched the Web but i couldn't find the solution. I have only tried typing instead of break, b and instead of *main, 1 (as first line of code) but none of that worked.

```
(gdb) break *main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005bd
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/spida/Documents/Hacking/license_1 
/bin/bash: /home/spida/Documents/Hacking/license_1: Permission denied
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /home/spida/Documents/Hacking/license_1: cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126.
(gdb)
```

Also at the video program stops running at the breakpoint so he could see registers info, for me registers were empty.

So sorry for English

Comment: That's because you don't have permissions to run the program

Comment: Surely the problem is the _"cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126."_? That suggests that your program is not running at all rather than ignoring the breakpoint.  Read the error messages - they tell you stuff! ;-)  I searched on _`gdb "cannot execute: Permission denied During startup program exited with code 126"`_ and came up with the issue for exactly your exercise: 
 "https://github.com/LiveOverflow/liveoverflow_youtube/issues/8"..  Have you set the executable attribute for your build?

Comment: As a programmer, you not only have to read the error messages when something is not working (like this situtation) but even when things appear to be working.

Comment: thanks everybody, i'll read in future

Comment: I've made it! :D I have made it executable using chmod +x license_1 and now it works! Thankss